# How to make a process wait for an other process

Tags: mpi

I have recently started programming in MPI (C language) and I have run into a situation where in among all the n process's I create, I need one process to explicitly wait for an another process. 
         I have gone through MPI_Barrier and MPI_Wait, but still not sure how it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe why you think it needs to wait? It's likely that you really don't need to do that.

Comment: Yes, I have a matrix and I am creating a process for every anti diagonal in it. In a n*n matrix, I will be having 2n-1 anti-diagonal(which is the number of process's). The situation is that a process has to wait for the previous process to execute, as it needs data from that. So in this case I would have to introduce a wait to make sure that I do not operate on old values.

Comment: an `n*n` matrix has `n` anti-diagonal elements.

Comment: I hope you mean previous *iteration*'s process, otherwise it sounds like you're making a sequential algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If you're explicitly expecting data from the process on which you want to wait, just call `MPI_Recv` with the source process named as the sender argument, and the receive call will block until the data is sent to it.

As noted by @Adam in an insightful comment on your question, what you're describing may be a fully sequential algorithm, which would be a rather unfortunate result in an MPI program.

Comment: @Ajinkya "block until" means "wait for".

Comment: Yes, I will try working with MPI_Recv. It seems a much better alternative than MPI_WAIT for my situation. Thank you